# In ETH ICO smart contracts, Is it normal to lock out an entire wallet or set coins?

Tags: tokens

I've recently participated in an ICO [icon] that completely locked my icon [myetherwallet]. Because I didn't complete the KYC, I know I shouldn't have the coins. However, because I was still interested in the ICON coins I purchased them on the open market and deposited them into the same myetherwallet. And as a result the myetherwallet is showing a balance of both the "dead" coins and the ones I purcahsed. The wallet doesn't allow me to transfer anything. I am just wondering if this is normal protocol in smart contract programming -- that is, to lock out an entire wallet. Can smart contracts be modified in these situations? Can this be resolve when the ERC20 coins are converted into mainnet coins? Several other people on different forums seems to be in similar situations. I've contacted ICON staff but I don't think they'll do much.

Thank you in advance

Cheers